# S7 Broken/Black Screen and no Digitizer. Rooted with TWRP

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, twrp, broken-screen, samsung-galaxy-s7

I have broken my S7 screen and now its completely black with no touch at all. Phone is rooted with TWRP custom recovery. I can access it though ADB from recovery but when booted normally i'm unauthorized. I did tried to push my PC's RSA Key to the S7 without success. I want to backup my phone's internal photos but i can't do anything atm without authorization. Is there anything i can do without replacing the screen through ADB on recovery or i am doomed?! Also could i get an otg mhl adapter to get image through the usb so maybe i could do something there? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advanced.

```
[dalvik.vm.dex2oat-Xmx]: [512m]
[dalvik.vm.dex2oat-filter]: [verify-at-runtime]
[dalvik.vm.image-dex2oat-Xms]: [64m]
[dalvik.vm.image-dex2oat-Xmx]: [64m]
[dalvik.vm.image-dex2oat-filter]: [verify-at-runtime]
[dalvik.vm.isa.arm.features]: [default]
[dalvik.vm.isa.arm.variant]: [cortex-a53]
[dalvik.vm.isa.arm64.features]: [default]
[dalvik.vm.isa.arm64.variant]: [cortex-a53]
[dalvik.vm.lockprof.threshold]: [500]
[dalvik.vm.stack-trace-file]: [/data/anr/traces.txt]
[dalvik.vm.usejit]: [true]
[debug.atrace.tags.enableflags]: [0]
[init.svc.adbd]: [running]
[init.svc.ldconfigtxt]: [stopped]
[init.svc.recovery]: [running]
[init.svc.set_permissive]: [stopped]
[init.svc.ueventd]: [running]
[keyguard.no_require_sim]: [true]
[mtp.crash_check]: [0]
[net.bt.name]: [Android]
[net.change]: [net.bt.name]
[persist.sys.dalvik.vm.lib.2]: [libart]
[persist.sys.root_access]: [1]
[persist.sys.usb.config]: [mtp,adb]
[ro.allow.mock.location]: [1]
[ro.arch]: [exynos8890]
[ro.baseband]: [unknown]
[ro.board.platform]: [exynos5]
[ro.boot.ap_serial]: [0x02F6CE577B5C]
[ro.boot.bootdevice]: [155a0000.ufs]
[ro.boot.bootloader]: [G930FXXU3ERL3]
[ro.boot.debug_level]: [0x4f4c]
[ro.boot.dram_info]: [01,05,00,4G]
[ro.boot.dram_rev]: [00000000]
[ro.boot.emmc_checksum]: [3]
[ro.boot.fmp_config]: [0]
[ro.boot.hardware]: [samsungexynos8890]
[ro.boot.hmac_mismatch]: [0]
[ro.boot.hw_rev]: [8]
[ro.boot.odin_download]: [1]
[ro.boot.sec_atd.tty]: [/dev/ttySAC4]
[ro.boot.security_mode]: [1526595585]
[ro.boot.selinux]: [enforcing]
[ro.boot.serialno]: [ad07160320f4e2aac2]
[ro.boot.ucs_mode]: [0]
[ro.boot.warranty_bit]: [1]
[ro.boot.wb.hs]: [030c]
[ro.bootimage.build.date.utc]: [1532923497]
[ro.bootimage.build.date]: [Mon Jul 30 04:04:57 UTC 2018]
[ro.bootimage.build.fingerprint]: [samsung/omni_herolte/herolte:6.0.1/MOB30M/4:eng/test-keys]
[ro.bootloader]: [G930FXXU3ERL3]
[ro.bootmode]: [unknown]
[ro.build.characteristics]: [default]
[ro.build.date.utc]: [0]
[ro.build.date]: [Mon Jul 30 03:59:52 UTC 2018]
[ro.build.display.id]: [omni_herolte-eng 6.0.1 MOB30M 4 test-keys]
[ro.build.flavor]: [omni_herolte-eng]
[ro.build.host]: [24fbe3db73ea]
[ro.build.id]: [MOB30M]
[ro.build.tags]: [test-keys]
[ro.build.type]: [eng]
[ro.build.user]: [jenkins]
[ro.build.version.all_codenames]: [REL]
[ro.build.version.base_os]: []
[ro.build.version.codename]: [REL]
[ro.build.version.incremental]: [4]
[ro.build.version.preview_sdk]: [0]
[ro.build.version.release]: [6.0.1]
[ro.build.version.sdk]: [23]
[ro.build.version.security_patch]: [2016-06-01]
[ro.carrier]: [unknown]
[ro.chipname]: [exynos8890]
[ro.com.android.dataroaming]: [true]
[ro.com.android.wifi-watchlist]: [GoogleGuest]
[ro.com.google.clientidbase]: [android-google]
[ro.config.alarm_alert]: [Argon.ogg]
[ro.config.notification_sound]: [pixiedust.ogg]
[ro.config.ringtone]: [Ring_Synth_04.ogg]
[ro.dalvik.vm.native.bridge]: [0]
[ro.debuggable]: [1]
[ro.hardware.keystore]: [mdfpp]
[ro.hardware]: [samsungexynos8890]
[ro.kernel.android.checkjni]: [1]
[ro.lcd_brightness]: [162]
[ro.lcd_min_brightness]: [0]
[ro.modversion]: [OmniROM-6.0.1-20180730-herolte-HOMEMADE]
[ro.omni.device]: [herolte]
[ro.omni.version]: [6.0.1-20180730-herolte-HOMEMADE]
[ro.product.board]: [universal8890]
[ro.product.brand]: [samsung]
[ro.product.cpu.abi]: [arm64-v8a]
[ro.product.cpu.abilist32]: [armeabi-v7a,armeabi]
[ro.product.cpu.abilist64]: []
[ro.product.cpu.abilist]: [armeabi-v7a,armeabi]
[ro.product.device]: [herolte]
[ro.product.locale]: [en-US]
[ro.product.manufacturer]: [samsung]
[ro.product.model]: [SM-G930F]
[ro.product.name]: [heroltexx]
[ro.revision]: [0]
[ro.sec.fle.encryption]: [true]
[ro.secure]: [0]
[ro.security.mdpp.release]: [8]
[ro.security.mdpp.ver]: [2.0]
[ro.serialno]: [ad07160320f4e2aac2]
[ro.setupwizard.enterprise_mode]: [1]
[ro.sf.lcd_density]: [560]
[ro.twrp.boot]: [1]
[ro.twrp.version]: [3.2.3-0]
[ro.url.legal]: [http://www.google.com/intl/%s/mobile/android/basic/phone-legal.html]
[ro.wifi.channels]: []
[ro.zygote]: [zygote32]
[security.mdpp.mass]: [skmm]
[security.mdpp.result]: [None]
[security.mdpp]: [None]
[service.adb.root]: [1]
[service.adb.tcp.port]: [5555]
[sys.usb.config]: [mtp,adb]
[sys.usb.state]: [mtp,adb]
[twrp.action_complete]: [0]
[twrp.crash_counter]: [0]
```

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=4111923

Comment: could you be more specific on what to look on those threads. Thanks

Comment: It seems that I have access. I can see the folder push content in it but the directory is empty. If I type ls in the data directory it's empty.